# I am trying create a button in which boolean function should be performed. below is my view code. Can anyone help me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<% if case.active? %>
  <%= form_for case do |f| %>
    <%= f.active_field :active, value: false %>
    <%= f.submit 'Unblock' %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= form_for case do |f| %>
    <%= f.active_field :active, value: true %>
    <%= f.submit 'block' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>`
```

Active is a field which is set a default to true and when I click block button it needs to change to unblock and the default boolean should be changed to false. Can you help me in getting the controller and view code? Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What errors are you getting for it ?

Comment: `case` is a reserved word. Try another name

Comment: the button doesnt work when its clicked. when its in checkbox format it works when changed to button it doesnt work

Comment: @SuseeHarini what do you mean by `f.active_field` is there any view helper named like `active_field` ?

Comment: `case` is a reserved word as mentioned by @Mezbah. While its technically possible to use it it not a good idea at all since you end up creating syntax errors and very confusing code.

Comment: @SuseeHarini feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically [button_to](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) tag in rails converts in to form itself into html.
so you can use this: -

note: - provide correct path and data that should be send with this button at controller

```
<% if case.active? %>    
  <%= button_to case_path(value: false), data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, method: :patch, class: 'btn btn-default btn-danger' do %>
  Unblock
  <% end %>
<%else%>
  <%= button_to case_path(value: true), data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, method: :patch, class: 'btn btn-default btn-danger' do %>
  block
  <% end %>
<%end%>
```

and at controller: -

```
def your_action
  case = Case.find(params[:id])
  case.update(active: params[:value])
end
```

Comment: This should be a `PATCH` or `PUT` request - not `POST`.